# Variation of a function with respect to the metric

Tags: metric-spaces, calculus-of-variations

I was reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04604) and I think that I find a mistake, may be I'm wrong, but  I want to be sure.

They take the variation with respect to the metric $g_{\alpha\beta}$ of this function

$$S(\delta \Omega)=\int_{\delta \Omega}n_{\nu}s^{\nu}\sqrt{h}d^{d-1}x$$

With some fixed boundary conditions $g_{\alpha\beta}(\delta \Omega)=g_{\alpha\beta}^{\delta \Omega}$. $s^{\nu}$ is a function that depends of the metric and $\delta\Omega$ is a Jordan Orientable surface with normal $n_{\nu}$.

They define a family of metrics

$$g_{\alpha\beta}(x^{\mu})=g*_{\alpha\beta}(\mu)+\delta_{\epsilon}(g_{\alpha\beta})x^{\mu} $$

Where $g*_{\alpha\beta}$ is the metric that extremize $S(\delta\Omega)$, $\epsilon\in R$. $\delta_{\epsilon}(g_{\alpha\beta})$ satisfices the boundary condition $\delta_{\epsilon}(g_{\alpha\beta})(\delta\Omega)=0$ and $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow    0} \delta_{\epsilon}(g_{\alpha\beta})(x^{\mu})=0$.

The the variation with respect to the metric of the first equation is

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\delta_{\epsilon(S)(\delta \Omega)}}{\epsilon}=0$$

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\delta_{\epsilon(S)(\delta \Omega)}}{\epsilon}=\int_{\delta \Omega}n_{\nu}\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{\delta_{\epsilon}(s^{\nu})}{\epsilon}\sqrt{h}d^{d-1}x=0$$
But I think that the last equation is wrong. I think that we also have to take the variation with respect  the metric of the normal $n_{\nu}$, something like this: 
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\delta_{\epsilon(S)(\delta \Omega)}}{\epsilon}=\int_{\delta \Omega}\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{\delta_{\epsilon}(n_{\nu}s^{\nu})}{\epsilon}\sqrt{h}d^{d-1}x=0$$

[Since](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100975/hypersurface-normal)

$$n_{\alpha}=\frac{\partial_{\alpha}f}{\sqrt{|g^{\alpha \beta}\partial_{\alpha}f \partial_{\beta}f   |   }}$$

$$\textbf{EDIT}$$
I'm not looking for the complete way of taking  the variation of this function. I'm looking for and answer that say's if I have to do something like this $\delta_{\epsilon}n_{\nu}(s^{\nu})$ or like this $\delta_{\epsilon}(n_{\nu}s^{\nu})$ in the variation.

Comment: Why are you including the $=0$??

Comment: What zero do you mean?

Comment: Right after "However, I don't agree with this equation". It seems you don't agree with the first equality. So why add the second equality? It just creates confusion.